# Changing div background color with click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So. I have 2 input (x,y) and when press submit code is draw divs (example: 5x5). I want to change divs background color when div is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Feladat10</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="x"/>
    <input type="text" name="y"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    echo "<br/>";
    for($i=1; $i <= $x; $i++)
    {
        echo "<br/><div class='tile'>".$i."</div>";
        for($j=1; $j < $y; $j++)
        {
            echo "<div class='tile'>".$j."</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Im trying with this code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".tile").click(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#000000');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But its not working. Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: what shows in console?

Comment: @Sanooj T Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: where is your jquery.js file

Comment: You will get this error when you not included your jquery file or when you included your jquery file after your script

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`  
add this in `<head>` section

Comment: holy ****, big mistake, thank you :) now working fine, dunno how i forget this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the jquery.min.js file in appropriate position.

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".tile").click(function () {
           $(this).css("background-color","black");
         });
      });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='tile'>one</div>
<div class='tile'>two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not find jquery attached to your html file

Comment: Put this inside your head tags

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>